# Dealing with large MLModel files and Github Repository

Tags: github, coreml

I have a Swift written app, the app itself contains a `.mlmodel` file that's rather large - 230MB. On the [Github's website](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/) you can read the following:

> GitHub will warn you when pushing files larger than 50 MB. You will not be allowed to push files larger than 100 MB.

When I try to push my project to the remote repository, I get the:

> The remote repository rejected commits.

Which is expected due to the large size. My question is how to deal with this situation? Is there a work around this?

Comment: You can try to compress this file and then push it to github

Comment: @megas even when compressed its still over 200MB

Comment: Don't use a 230 MB model! That's way too big for mobile.

Comment: Then the only choice is to use online file storage like dropbox. There's an api to upload/download from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep a reference of that large file (>200MB) in your GitHub repository, you would nee to:

- activate [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/), adding your large file to your repo [as in this tutorial](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial)
- push a reference to your GitHub repo

As [detailed here](https://help.github.com/articles/about-storage-and-bandwidth-usage/):

- Git LFS is available for every repository on GitHub, whether or not your account or organization has a paid plan.
- Every account using Git Large File Storage receives 1 GB of free storage and 1 GB a month of free bandwidth